# How to access class(implements Runnable) field

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

i want to control thread by input value.

if input value is 1 than do something.

else nothing.

```
class Main {
  class test implements Runnable{
    public boolean flag = true;
    public int val = 0;

    @Override 
    public void run(){
      while(true){
        if(flag == true){
          pt();
        }
      }
    }

    public void pt(){
      System.out.println(val++);
      flag = false;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    test r = m.new test();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
      int n = reader.nextInt();
      if(n==1){
        r.flag = true;
        // t.flag = true;
      }
      else{
        r.flag = false;
        // t.flag = false;
      }
   }
  }
}
```

This is my code.

Obviously, 
I knowing that r.flag does not change the value of Thread t.
So, even if typing 1, Nothing happens.
but t.flag is impossible. object t have not variable flag.

How to access t.r.flag .... can you understand?

I think something is making a lot of fools right now.

Am I going in a wrong direction?

Comment: as a rule of thumb, common variables (here test.flag) should be accessed from within synchronized methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Change `public boolean flag = true;` to `public volatile boolean flag = true;`

JVM optimized the code by caching the value of flag because it is 'obvious' that it would be be changed.

Comment: Do you know Google?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html